# Elasticsearch: Adding manual mapping using Java

Tags: java, performance, mapping, elasticsearch

I cant change the mapping. Can anybody help me to find the bug in my code? 
I have found this standard way to change the mapping according to several tutorials. But when i'm try to call the mapping structure there just appear a blank mapping structure after manuall mapping creation.
But after inserting some data there appear the mapping specification because ES is using of course the default one. To be more specific see the code below.

```
public class ElasticTest {
private String dbname = "ElasticSearch";
private String index = "indextest";
private String type = "table";
private Client client = null;
private Node node = null;

public ElasticTest(){
    this.node = nodeBuilder().local(true).node();
    this.client = node.client();

    if(isIndexExist(index)){
        deleteIndex(this.client, index);
        createIndex(index);
    }
    else{
        createIndex(index);
    }

    System.out.println("mapping structure before data insertion");
    getMappings();
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    createData();
    System.out.println("mapping structure after data insertion");
    getMappings();



}

public void getMappings() {
    ClusterState clusterState = client.admin().cluster().prepareState()
            .setFilterIndices(index).execute().actionGet().getState();
    IndexMetaData inMetaData = clusterState.getMetaData().index(index);
    MappingMetaData metad = inMetaData.mapping(type);

    if (metad != null) {
        try {
            String structure = metad.getSourceAsMap().toString();
            System.out.println(structure);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private void createIndex(String index) {
    XContentBuilder typemapping = buildJsonMappings();
    String mappingstring = null;
    try {
        mappingstring = buildJsonMappings().string();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    client.admin().indices().create(new CreateIndexRequest(index)
                  .mapping(type, typemapping)).actionGet();

    //try put mapping after index creation
    /*
     * PutMappingResponse response = null; try { response =
     * client.admin().indices() .preparePutMapping(index) .setType(type)
     * .setSource(typemapping.string()) .execute().actionGet(); } catch
     * (ElasticSearchException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch
     * (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
     */

}

private void deleteIndex(Client client, String index) {
    try {
        DeleteIndexResponse delete = client.admin().indices()
                .delete(new DeleteIndexRequest(index)).actionGet();
        if (!delete.isAcknowledged()) {
        } else {
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

private XContentBuilder buildJsonMappings(){
    XContentBuilder builder = null; 
    try {
        builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
        builder.startObject()
        .startObject("properties")
            .startObject("ATTR1")
                .field("type", "string")
                .field("store", "yes")
                .field("index", "analyzed")
             .endObject()
           .endObject()
        .endObject();           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder;
}

private boolean isIndexExist(String index) {
    ActionFuture<IndicesExistsResponse> exists = client.admin().indices()
            .exists(new IndicesExistsRequest(index));
    IndicesExistsResponse actionGet = exists.actionGet();

    return actionGet.isExists();
}

private void createData(){
    System.out.println("Data creation");
    IndexResponse response=null;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        json.put("ATTR1", "new value" + i);
        response = this.client.prepareIndex(index, type)
                .setSource(json)
                .setOperationThreaded(false)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
    }
    String _index = response.getIndex();
    String _type = response.getType();
    long _version = response.getVersion();
    System.out.println("Index : "+_index+"   Type : "+_type+"   Version : "+_version);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new ElasticTest();
}
}
```

I just wanna change the property of ATTR1 field to analyzed to ensure fast queries.
What im doing wrong? I also tried to create the mapping after index creation but it leads to the same affect.

Answer (score 5):

Ok i found the answer by my own. On the type level i had to wrap the "properties" with the type name. E.g:

"type1" : {
   "properties" : {
      .....
   }
}

See the following code:

```
private XContentBuilder getMappingsByJson(){
    XContentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject().startObject(type).startObject("properties");
        for(int i = 1; i<5; i++){
            builder.startObject("ATTR" + i)
                    .field("type", "integer")
                    .field("store", "yes")
                    .field("index", "analyzed")
                    .endObject();
            }
            builder.endObject().endObject().endObject();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return builder;
}
```

It creates mappings for the attributes ATTR1 - ATTR4. Now it is possible to define mapping for Example a list of different attributes dynamically. Hope it helps someone else.